# Clustering spherical-shaped data

Tags: clustering, spectral-analysis

I have a data set that consists of census data (5 attributes). Performing PCA, I found that the original data looks like a big chunk (please look at the first picture), and therefore, I decided to use spectral clustering, and the picture below is the representation of the data (the picture is obtained by plotting the highest three eigenvectors of the Laplacian). The shape looks interesting to me and it looks like these data form sort of a function in the new domain (I really would like to hear a better interpretation from experts).

[image]
[image: My data]

**I now have 2 questions:**

(1) what can we say about the data in the new domain?

(2) What is the best clustering technique you suggest to perform the clustering

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen such patterns arise if you have some correlation in your data; or a scenario like that. It did not yield any benefits for analysis - usually the pattern was easier to understand, detect, and analyze in the original domain.

I don't think clustering will get you anywhere. There is **only a single cluster** in my opinion, based on your visualizations.

You have a bunch of outliers there. You could try removing them, and then check if you can get a better projection. PCA is sensitive to outliers; you can see that the first two components are mostly used to distinguish the outliers; there could be information hidden in the other dimensions.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In fact, you are right, the correlation is very high, about 85% of the elements of `corr(t(X))` are larger than 0.9. But even the original data looks like a chunk and there is a single cluster (if outliers are removed), which I will be doing so now. Do you suggest a clustering technique to be applied to the original data?

Comment: I don't have any recommendations, because by the visualizations there is only one cluster in the data. The data might be just a "chunk"?